# filtering specific time for each date in data table in r

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with one of the columns as date time

```
data = data.table::data.table(date_time = c("2019-05-20 14:20:00","2019-05-20 14:21:00","2019-05-20 14:22:00","2019-05-20 14:23:00","2019-05-20 14:24:00",
                                            "2019-05-21 14:20:00","2019-05-20 14:21:00","2019-05-20 14:22:00","2019-05-20 14:23:00","2019-05-20 14:24:00",
                                            "2019-05-20 14:20:00","2019-05-20 14:21:00","2019-05-20 14:22:00","2019-05-20 14:23:00","2019-05-20 14:24:00")  )


data[ , date_time := as.POSIXct(date_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s") ]
```

I want to remove all rows which contain time between 14:21:00 and 14:23:00 for each date.

I tried solutions in [R Filtering Time Series data for each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36736498/r-filtering-time-series-data-for-each-group) and [R Filtering data using reference time table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49519077/r-filtering-data-using-reference-time-table-in-r) but they are not replicable for each date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `lubridate`, using `hms` periods.
This approach allows to have different start & end hours:

```r
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)


data[ , date_time := as.POSIXct(date_time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") ]


data[!between(date_time,floor_date(date_time,'day')+hms('14:21:00'),
                        floor_date(date_time,'day')+hms('14:23:00'))]

#             date_time
#                <POSc>
#1: 2019-05-20 14:20:00
#2: 2019-05-20 14:24:00
#3: 2019-05-21 14:20:00
#4: 2019-05-20 14:24:00
#5: 2019-05-20 14:20:00
#6: 2019-05-20 14:24:00
```

Comment: I wanted to remove these values not keep them. Any way to modify this code to remove the specific values?

Comment: use `!between`?

Comment: thanks a ton! one last thing, suppose i have another column in this data table called "weekday" and I only want to put this !between function on weekday == "friday"..how do i do that? @Waldi

Comment: `!(weekday == "friday")|((weekday == "friday")&(!between(...)))`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using `data.table`, it has convenient functions `hour` and `minute` which you can use here.

```
library(data.table)

data[ , date_time := as.POSIXct(date_time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %T")]
data[!(hour(date_time) == 14 & between(minute(date_time), 21, 23))]

#             date_time
#1: 2019-05-20 14:20:00
#2: 2019-05-20 14:24:00
#3: 2019-05-21 14:20:00
#4: 2019-05-20 14:24:00
#5: 2019-05-20 14:20:00
#6: 2019-05-20 14:24:00
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Actually the data table is much longer with time ranging from 00:00:00 to 23:59:00 and i want to remove all date time from 14:31:00 to 22:29:00 for each date. So, how can i increase the hour argument in your solution?